# Is it possible to make a soap client dynamic by importing WSDL file

Tags: java, soap

I am writing tests in cucumber for testing the soap service present at the remote server. They also have WSDL defined at the server side. I want to create the client by importing that wsdl file at the run time. I have searched on internet the only I could figure out is by using wsimport command.

But that approach would not be possible if you make parse the WSDL file at runtime and you have client generating code at runtime.

Could you please help me understand how can I make it dynamic meaning reading the WSDL file at runtime and creating client out of it at runtime?

Comment: You want to create the code from which WSDL was created?

Comment: Yes, at runtime without using wsimport command.